# Move files from Regional to Multiregional Bucket in GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-data-transfer

I have a "nearline" + "europe-west4 (Netherlands)" bucket in the Google Computer Engine. If the files in the bucket reach a certain age (say, 6 months), I'd like to move them to a "coldline" + "mutli-regional (EU)" bucket. I tried implementing this behaviour using the bucket lifecycle rules, but unfortunately the documentation says, that you cannot move files from a "regional" to a "multiregional" bucket.

How can I implement this behaviour? Is there some other means of doing this apart from the bucket life cycle rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, accordingly to the documentation [Lifecycle actions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle#actions):

> For buckets in a region, the new storage class cannot be
>   Multi-Regional Storage.

As result, **if you want to use Lifecycle to manage Storage Class of your data you should switch to using the same location** region or multi-region. More information you can find in the documentation [Bucket locations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations):

> **Use a region** to help optimize latency and network bandwidth for data
>   consumers, such as analytics pipelines, that are grouped in the same
>   region.

and

> **Use a multi-region** when you want to serve content to data consumers
>   that are outside of the Google network and distributed across large
>   geographic areas, or when you want the higher availability that comes
>   with being geo-redundant.

**As a possible workaround** you can try [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs):

> Storage Transfer Service allows you to quickly import online data into
>   Cloud Storage. You can also set up a repeating schedule for
>   transferring data, as well as transfer data within Cloud Storage, from
>   one bucket to another.

You can schedule daily transfers between your region and multi-region buckets using as filter like **`Filter transferred files by last-modified time`** with **`Min age`** and **`Max age`** in hours, and options like **`Delete objects from source once they are transferred`**.